# Backbone router working differently with utf-8 characters on Safari and Chrome

Tags: backbone.js, utf-8

I have this example, using a route with an utf-8 non-ascii character:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Backbone Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

   <script>

        (function(){

        window.App = {
            Models: {},
            Collections: {},
            Views: {},
            Router: {}
        };

        })();

        App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                'charñ': 'charChrome',
                'char%C3%B1': 'charSafari'
            },

            charChrome: function(){
                $(document.body).append("Chrome-compatible route triggered.<br/>");
            },

            charSafari: function(){
                $(document.body).append("Safari-compatible route triggered.<br/>");
            },

        });

        new App.Router;
        Backbone.history.start();

   </script>

   <h1>HELLO THERE</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When the page got called with something like:

```
file://localhost/whatever.html#charñ
```

...it trigger a different function on Safari and Chrome.

It's REALLY not easy for me to change backbone version.

Is there a way to avoid that difference?

Note: interesting enough, removing the meta tag breaks Chrome routing.

Comment: Safari and Firefox or Safari and Chrome? The title of the question doesn't match the question

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference, but have you tried the HTML5 method of specifying the encoding as you're using the HTML5 doctype? (`<meta charset="utf-8">`)

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: sorry, Chrome. I fixed it.

Comment: @jab: yes, it doesn't solve the problem, alas.

Comment: @St0rM I'd try on Firefox/Opera or other browsers to check which behavior is used on other browsers.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: Firefox seems to have the same behaviour of Safari. I'll gire Opera a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be seen as an answer to that makes every browsers works the same but prevent this from happening. As far as I know, there is no much control on what backone will trigger. It's not like you can really filter the url before it gets handled by the `Router`.

That said, you can create routes for both style. To make this easier, you can create a special object that will get a utf8 string and create a urlencoded version of the route. Both routes will have the same callback.

On other possibility is to avoid utf-8 symbols in the url and report a bug to backbonejs. Having both routes created with urlencoded/urldecoded will make the site work for possibly every browsers supporting javascript. The downside is that you'll have to create `n*2` routes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried decoding the URL when it's passed to your function? It may be that Chrome decodes the URL for you while Safari does not. `'char%C3%B1'` will decode to `'charñ'` just fine when using a URI decoder, and it should have no effect on already-decoded strings (assuming the encoding used was the correct one, of course).

```js
decodeURIComponent('char%C3%B1')

/*
charñ
*/
decodeURIComponent('charñ')

/*
charñ
*/
```

Going by http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-156, you may be able to substitute `_extractParameters` with a version that calls `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` on `fragment` before executing the regular expression.

Another possibility to try, as I just noticed that routes can be regular expressions (see http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-152): if you don't have many of them, you could use something like `/char(ñ|%C3%B1)/g`, or write a function to produce such a regular expression for the unencoded value, such that `makeRegex('charñ')` would produce `/char(ñ|%C3%B1)/g`, or whatever the regular expression would be.

Comment: @St0rM Going by http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-156, the values are decoded only _after_ matching URI fragments to routes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an additional line in the while loop, inside _bindRoutes, to bind the encoded routes as well:

```
_bindRoutes: function() {
  if (!this.routes) return;
  this.routes = _.result(this, 'routes');
  var route, routes = _.keys(this.routes);
  while ((route = routes.pop()) != null) {
    this.route(route, this.routes[route]);
    //add this line:
    this.route(encodeURIComponent(route).replace(/%2F/g,'/').replace(/%3A/g,':'), this.routes[route]);
  }
}
```